# What is the meaning of this Divya Prabandham verse?

Tags: alwar, om, divya-prabhandham

viShNuChitta in his Periyazhwar Thirumozhi [4.7.10](https://archive.org/details/thesacredbookoffourthousand02ocrtxtlayernalayiradivyaprabandhamsriramabharati2000/page/n83/mode/2up) (overall pasuram #400) says:

> மூன்றெழுத்ததனை மூன்றெழுத்ததனால் மூன்றெழுத்தாக்கி மூன்றெழுத்தை
> ஏன்றுகொண்டிருப்பார்க்கு இரக்கம் நன்குடைய எம்புருடோத்தமனிருக்கை
> மூன்றடி நிமிர்த்து மூன்றினில் தோன்றி மூன்றினில் மூன்றுருவானான்
>
> mU^nR^ezhuttada^nai mU^nR^ezhuttada^nAl mU^nR^ezhuttAkki mU^nR^ezhuttai
> e^nRuk^oNDiruppArkku irakkam^ na^nguDaiya ^empuruDottamanirukkai
> mU^nRaDi nimirttu mU^nRi^nil to^nRi mU^nRi^nil mU^nRuruvA^nA^n
>
> The three syllables A-U-M, by three-syllable Nirukta, become the three, Akara-Ukara-Makara. Contemplating the three syllables OM expanded to three words with Namo-Narayanaya shows the three aspects of the Atman in three relationships with the Supreme manifested in three forms.

I was very confused by the lists of three in this verse, and I don't know Tamil. **What are the "three aspects", "three relationships" and "three forms" referenced in this verse?**

Comment: this is not the best forum for discussing prabandha rahasya. kalakshepam under bonafide guru is the way.

Comment: @mar That is true, but maybe an overview would be helpful?

Comment: If pictures are not immanent to the context of your question, I'd please suggest you to not use them.

Comment: I removed the image

Comment: Are definitions of words and lists "rahasya"? @mar

Comment: @Vedavedya - by that logic, anything can be called as rahasya or not rahasya :). after all everything is communicated with words/definitions

Comment: I'm just wondering what you would call "prabandha rahasya" that can only be taught by a guru

Comment: @Vedavedya - if u know Tamil, it is specifically called Aruliccheyal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this https://ramanuja.org/sri/BhaktiListArchives/Article?p=rest2003%2F0006.html website, the meaning of above Divya Prabandham verse is told

> Three aspects of Supreme Lordship of Narayanan are - Seshithvam,
> Saranyathvam, Prapyathvamkaan.
>
> Three relationships are
>
> 1. Ananya Seshathvam - not being a servant to anyone else
> 2. Ananya Saranathvam - There is no refuge other than Him
> 3. Ananya Bhogyathvam - the only bliss and enjoyment is in serving lotus feet of Bhagavan
>
> The 3 Forms which Lord took in Trivikrama avatar : Asked for three
> measures of his feet nimirtthu- [with one step] took huge form
> moonrinil- Bhumi (earth), Anthariksham (space) and Swargam (heaven)